# Не работают шейдеры в OpenGL ES 2.0 на Андроид 4.2.2

Tags: android-studio, opengles

Проблема с загрузкой шейдеров. Делал по урокам. На Андроид 5.1.1 все работает, на 4.2.2, возникает ошибка с шейдерами. Т.е он не хочет их считывать, проверку сделал вот такого рода. Как можно решить эту проблему?

```
int fragmentShaderId = ShaderUtils.createShader(context, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, R.raw.fragment_shader);
if (fragmentShaderId == 0) Log.e("fragmentShaderId", "0");
```

Проверка может показаться не правильной, но при запуске на 5.1.1 ошибок в логах нет.

Как запилить шейдеры по другому?

Лог ошибок:

```
08-15 16:16:23.431 31539-31539/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.drawableHotspotChanged, referenced from method android.support.design.internal.ForegroundLinearLayout.drawableHotspotChanged
08-15 16:16:23.431 31539-31539/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17092: Landroid/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutCompat;.drawableHotspotChanged (FF)V
08-15 16:16:23.431 31539-31539/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
08-15 16:16:23.561 31539-31555/? E/fragmentShaderId: 0
08-15 16:16:23.561 31539-31555/? E/programm id:  = 0
08-15 16:28:18.281 31539-31539/com.example.vladimir.newopengles W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 16:28:18.281 31539-31539/com.example.vladimir.newopengles W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 16:28:18.291 31539-31539/com.example.vladimir.newopengles W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 16:28:18.291 31539-31539/com.example.vladimir.newopengles W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 16:30:35.721 31539-31543/com.example.vladimir.newopengles D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 345K, 5% free 8335K/8712K, paused 27ms+4ms, total 159ms
08-15 16:33:00.741 31539-31555/com.example.vladimir.newopengles E/fragmentShaderId: 0
08-15 16:33:00.741 31539-31555/com.example.vladimir.newopengles E/programm id:  = 0
08-15 16:38:01.471 31539-31539/com.example.vladimir.newopengles W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 16:38:01.471 31539-31539/com.example.vladimir.newopengles W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 16:38:01.541 31539-31539/com.example.vladimir.newopengles W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 16:38:01.541 31539-31539/com.example.vladimir.newopengles W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-15 16:44:38.451 31539-31555/com.example.vladimir.newopengles E/fragmentShaderId: 0
08-15 16:44:38.451 31539-31555/com.example.vladimir.newopengles E/programm id:  = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

08-15 16:16:23.561 31539-31555/? E/fragmentShaderId: 0
08-15 16:16:23.561 31539-31555/? E/programm id:  = 0

0 - означает что шейдер fragmentShader  не скомпилился и как сдедствие весь programm . Надо смотреть текст шейдеров и искать там ошибки.

Если это не коммерческая тайна выкладывай текст, поковыряемся.